# How to include superscripted value in TLabel using Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using Delphi for developing an Android application. I need to display '2<sup>3</sup>' in a label (the exponent needs to be displayed in a smaller font and needs to appear higher than then base).

Is it possible to implement this in the same label?

Comment: Descend a new component from TLabel and write over the Paint virtual method. Furthermore add a  new powerCaption : string and a poweFont : TFont property to it.

Comment: Unicode has a [`U+00B3 SUPERSCRIPT THREE`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b3/index.htm) character.  If the label doesn't already render that character the way you want, you could override `Paint()` like Bitman suggested, just have it parse the current `Text` to separate the `2` and `3` (no need for a separate property), and then draw the two characters separately as needed.  Otherwise, just use 2 separate labels.

Comment: If you want to display this constant string, Remy's solution is the best.